# How much sense does it make to average (lat,lon) samples in order to increase 2D accuracy of a GPS location?

Tags: gps, point, geolocation, accuracy, sampling

Several GPS applications, like [this one](http://android.ranitos.de/manual/usersguide/advanced-waypoint-averaging/), or [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.destil.gpsaveraging&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5kZXN0aWwuZ3BzYXZlcmFnaW5nIl0.), acquire multiple (lat,lon) samples of a given location, assuming that the GPS unit is not moving, and then take an average of the samples in order to compute a "more precise" 2D location.

*(We do not care about the elevation/altitude position here!)*

The second app ([GPS Averaging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.destil.gpsaveraging&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5kZXN0aWwuZ3BzYXZlcmFnaW5nIl0.)) uses the accuracy value associated to each sample as a weight for the current location, and then calculates the weighted average accordingly. It also provides an estimate of the accuracy of the averaged location.

**Questions:**

**1)** While common sense pushes us to believe that averaging should lead to increased accuracy, **how much sense does it make for handheld units like phones** (i.e. simple devices that do not use differential GPS)?

**2) Would you recommend another method than [GPS Averaging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.destil.gpsaveraging&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5kZXN0aWwuZ3BzYXZlcmFnaW5nIl0.)'s method to compute the average location?**

**3) How to compute an estimate of the accuracy of the averaged location?**

**4) Is there a way different than averaging to get a better 2D positioning** by acquiring multiple (lat,lon) samples of a given location?

---

**UPDATE 1:** results of my preliminary study with 2 handheld GPS units (Sony phone models ST15i and ST17i) acquiring 3m accuracy fixes at the same position during 4.5 hours gave the following data:

[image: ST15i Results]
[image: ST17i Results]

**=> It is quite interesting to note that even though the supposed accuracy of the fixes was 3 meters, the ST17i model had lots of points further than 3 meters from the median/average.**

**=> Also remarkable is the monotone drift of the longitude on the ST15i model.**

(Note that the ST15i seems to have a more sensitive antenna than the ST17i as I could analyse it used on average 3 more satellites for its fixes than the ST15i!)

---

**UPDATE 2:** some further stats and numbers, still from the same datasets

[image: ST15i Summary] 
[image: ST17i Summary]
[image: Combined P-Plots]

**=> The data is definitely not normal**

**=> I also computed the distance between the median location of the ST15i and the median location of the ST17i: it is 3 meters, as if the study was playing with us, since all fixes used had an accuracy of 3 meters or better. This definitely validates the suggestion below of using a known reference in order to derive meaningful conclusions about the accuracy of each GPS unit!**

Comment: There's been a lot of [sunspot activity lately](http://www.space.com/15643-monster-sunspot-unleashes-solar-flares.html).  Given the [effect of the ionosphere on GPS signals](http://gauss.gge.unb.ca/gpsworld/EarlyInnovationColumns/Innov.1991.04.pdf), I wonder if the date you chose to sample is biased.  In other words, maybe you'd need to average over 11 years - a full [solar cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cycle).

Comment: LOL :) Thanks for the link about the solar activity effect. It indeed mentions that it can be the largest source of error in positioning, exceptionally as high as 100 m. To the 11-year period must be added as well the 10-minute traveling ionospheric disturbance and the 27-day solar rotational cycles. Wondering  now if my units are dual-frequency P-code as I could not find the datasheet of the Qualcomm GPSOneExtra CPU-embedded chip online (will try to contact them!).

Comment: Note, though, that my two units were acquiring fixes during the very same period, and behaved quite differently. Also note that they both used combined positioning, ie used both the data from GPS and GLONASS systems. Since my update yesterday I also noted that the ST15i unit had a similar HDOP to the ST17i, but apparently has a more sensitive antenna since it was using on average 3 more satellites than the ST17i - this probably explains why the ST15i graph shows a much smaller dispersion.

Comment: This said, Kirk, you are right that further tests will be very useful in understanding further the accuracy of my units. Could post my results here if interested, although I am not sure it is the most suitable location. Any comment on that?

Comment: Would you happen to be near a [CORS](http://geodesy.noaa.gov/CORS/) or some other location with known accurate coordinates that you can use for calibration?  Without a calibration location, I guess you can only get better _precision_, but not better _accuracy_.  I think your charts are great!  If you have more results I think just adding here would be fine.

Comment: No, unfortunately the closest CORS is more than 2,000 km away, as I am currently in Brazil. When you are saying "or some other location", would you have indications about the easiest way of finding such a location for calibration? Should I try to contact a local topographer?

Comment: Do you know anyone who has a survey grade GPS?  They should be able to provide you with a calibration point.  Not sure if it matters, but I think the closer you are to a CORS, the more accurate the survey-grade point would be.

Comment: The updates are interesting and valuable.  Note, though, that **of course** the distance from the median will not be normally distributed! Distances can't even be negative.  If the drift is *bivariate normal,* then theory shows the distance (to the *mean* location) will have a scaled [chi distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). Over short times--during which patterns like those shown here are apparent--you will see artifacts of the high positive temporal correlation.  Thus, the histograms and probability plots aren't telling us anything new.

Comment: whuber: insightful, thanks, it gave me the opportunity of learning a bit more about statistics! Let me just point out that the histograms and probability plots were done using the actual distance (i.e. positive value) from the median. But this does not take any value off of your last comment and the distribution actually looks like a chi distribution.

Comment: All in all, I am starting to understand all the intricacies of a GPS location accuracy: it is **way** more complex than what I first thought. It's making me wonder about the following: keeping the true positioning aside, and using a ref point to which we could come back regularly during a terrain survey, would it make sense to correct i.e. increase the accuracy of (through linear approximation?) the surveyed locations and/or path according to the drift of the reference point location? I should maybe open a new question for that one unless the answer is quick and easy and someone posts it here!

Comment: @whuber: I just checked the histograms of the individual latitude and longitude parameters and found them both to be non-normal. Was that expected as well?

Comment: (2) Due to the strong temporal correlation I would expect non-normality over relatively short periods, John, but over long periods the histograms should become symmetric and probably fairly close to normal (with the usual attendant outliers, no doubt). Difficult locations for receiving the signals might present exceptions to this general rule, depending on how the signals are compromised. (1) (Re an earlier comment) It sounds like you have re-invented differential correction :-).

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/analysis-of-gps-error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Averaging only makes sense if you assume that the "noise" in your location measurements is roughly symmetrical - evenly distributed in every direction. That is, for any one measurement, it's equally likely to be wrong in any particular direction.

It is probably possible that you could get a noise distribution that **isn't** symmetrical. For example, if your GPS device systematically underestimates the distance to all satellites, and is using more satellites from from a given direction (perhaps you're standing at the bottom of a cliff), then all measurements are more likely to be biased in that direction. In this instance, averaging will improve precision, but it won't fix your bias problem.

I don't know whether such over/underestimation is common, but I doubt it would be significant enough in most devices to reduce the utility of averaging. Perhaps it might introduce a little bias, but the increase in precision would still improve reliability (eg. for geocaching).

Regarding your 4 questions:

1. Depends how much much you value reliability over time spent standing in one spot, waiting for extra measurements.
2. That app doesn't mention it's method, but it probably uses plain averaging. Taking the median may be more reliable, but without knowing the noise distribution, it'd be hard to say. I would assume gaussian noise, in which case if you get enough measurements, they'll be about the same. A better method might be to use multiple devices, take many measurements with each device, and then average the entire set. This would remove device-specific biases, but would obviously not be quick or easy to do (if your devices do averaging themselves, then you could just average the averages - same result).
3. You can only estimate the precision, not the bias. If you assume gaussian noise, you can calculate a [confidence interval](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/confint.htm) around your estimate (average), based on your standard error. Some units to this live (based on the number of satellites), and represent the confidence interval by a circle around your position.
4. Probably not, unless you know of particular systematic errors that your device makes. See 2.

Comment: +1--good analysis and advice. But note that asymmetry of the noise and lack of bias are different things: the noise distribution can, in principle, be strongly asymmetrical and still be accurate. Concerning (4), there are more approaches available once one appreciates that the "noise" has a component that is positively correlated over time (a slowly moving "drift"). This implies that waiting longer between obtaining fixes may improve the accuracy of the averages. It also implies that standard errors estimated from a short series of fixes will usually optimistically overestimate the precision.

Comment: Thank you naught101, this was the sort of answer I was expecting, and it confirmed my thinking, especially after having found and read some nice articles about GPS precision, available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20081205091256/http://www.erols.com/dlwilson/gps.htm). I understand that everything is, in fact, linked to the characteristics of my own GPS, and things can change with other GPS chips and manufacturers. I guess I'll try to gather a huge dataset of fixes, if possible during several days, in order to confirm my assumptions.

Comment: Forgot to mention that all fixes will be taken if possible at a known geo-referenced point as measured by a topographer... After that, I guess what I'll do in my own implementation is that I'll average my fixes making sure I have a way of getting rid of outliers. I am thinking I'll perform a weighted averaging using HDOP values to give priority to the higher accuracy fixes.

Comment: Regarding your answer to 3), I confirm my unit returns for each fix a confidence radius, that I will be recording with each point, but I am a bit unclear about exactly what to do with it as I am not a statistics expert. I did some research, and I found [this interesting link](http://haywood.freeshell.org/wp1/midpoint.htm). Does it correspond to your idea? I do not understand how the "Combined Accuracy" is calculated there (for the given example "treasure2" with confidence radiuses of 5m and 6m), the computed "Combined Accuracy" is 5.125531: where does it come from?

Comment: whuber, I also thank you for your interesting clarification. It does make a lot of sense that the final accuracy of a set of points all acquired within a short interval, even if the set is large, will always "suffer" from a similar satellite configuration. So combining several, perhaps shorter, sets of points taken at various times of the day, ensuring a good spread over the 24h GPS cycle, or even over several days, will probably increase the final accuracy. I will verify this assumption!

Comment: @whuber interesting point. I assume you're talking about [GPS drift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986926/gps-drift-during-the-receiver-is-stationed)? If so, is that something that happens monotonically, or does it right itself somewhat when new satellites come into view? I mean, if it's monotonic, then the longer you stand in one place, the more your average will drift too. How do you account for that?

Comment: @JohnDoisneau: an experiment sounds like a great idea. My understanding is that because all the data points are drawn from the same distribution (if you account for whuber's point about drift), then the uncertainty in the individual measurements is going to be similar to the uncertainty between measurements, and you can more or less ignore the confidence radius for each individual measurement, and just calculate a new one for the whole data set.

Comment: @naught, Those are great questions in your latest comment. Briefly, we can view the error as a random process, but we don't have to assume it's continuous in time: it can have jumps, as you suggest. The GPS is designed so that *over long periods of time*, the error at an uncluttered location will average out to zero. (This is the rationale for taking long-term readings at fixed stations to measure the rate of continental drift.) The "drift" is a positively autocorrelated component of the error process. The autocorrelation means errors won't average out immediately, but they should eventually.

Comment: (Continued) I will add that a zero average error is not guaranteed, however. That's what we do differential correction for: it assesses the bias, which is a *fixed*, *constant* error.  The bias--essentially by definition--does not change over time.

Comment: Wow, this almost goes beyond what I am able to understand... whuber, do most of GPS units have a non-zero constant error (bias)? Also, still waiting for some help about you guys' evaluation of [that link](http://haywood.freeshell.org/wp1/midpoint.htm) and what sort of algo was used to compute the "Combined Accuracy"... See my earlier comment about question 3) above...

Comment: @JohnDoisneau: Haywood's page has a "results" section that describes in adequate detail what's going on. Play around with the "insert example" button and you'll see how it works. I don't know off-hand how they compare, but I **think** just using the variance of the points is probably going to give you more reliable and consistent results than Haywood's method - in particular, if *any* pair of points in your sample have uncertainty circles that don't overlap, then the intersection is empty, so Haywood's "combined accuracy" can't be calculated.

Comment: (cont)  On the other hand, Haywood's method of weighted averaging using the inverse of the point uncertainties seems like it might be a good idea. Not sure if it'd necessarily be a great improvement over unweighted averaging though..

Comment: Thank you very much naught101. I am accepting this as the answer and I have to say that your help was the prototype of an expert's help! Take care.

Comment: @John (re nonzero bias) I doubt any decent GPS unit has a nonzero bias, but individual *locations* conceivably could create biases in all GPS receivers near them, especially locations in particularly cluttered areas.  I base this (somewhat speculative) comment on theory rather than actual experience, though.

Answer (score -2):

Using two identical gps devices with one at a known location. Can't you work out the error for each gps reading and pass that error data on the the second gps unit and use it to correct the data ?

Comment: Is this a comment or is it a new question? If so, please consult our [help] for guidance on creating posts here.  If it's intended as an answer, would you mind augmenting it to provide a fuller explanation?